# Is that possible to create one connected app with pin protection enabled which support pin protection in other organizations

Tags: connected-apps, mobilesdk

I was trying to use salesforce mobile sdk to create a react native app. Then I created one connected app in Organization A, then login to Org A, I can see the pin protection and bio-metrics enabled. But when login to Org B or C, the pin protection does not work.

Is that possible to make it work in other organizations like B or C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up-to Salesforce org administrator to configure this [behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_mobile.htm&type=5) for the Connected App.

Every org that goes through the Authorization via OAuth, the Salesforce System Admin will see the Connected App under `Set Up > Connected Apps > Manage Connected App`

The Admin can click to edit the policies and enable the PIN protection and select PIN length as shown below under the **Mobile Integration**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The situation now is I am using Organization A's community user to login, I could see the pin protection and bio-metrics enabled. But when I was using Organization B's community user to login Org B(The mobile app use the same consumer key of Org A's connected app), I could not  see the pin protection or bio-metrics feature.

Comment: Did you check the connected apps in org B. Just set the connected app policy for mobile integration as my answer in org B and that should be it

Comment: Cool, thanks very much.
I found that I need to install the connected app(created in Org A) in Org B, which under `Set Up -> Connected Apps OAuth Usage`, just like you mentioned. 
You helped a lot, really really appreciate.

Comment: @Yixuan Please mark the answer as answered so it helps everyone.